# How to process data after ReceiveAsync

Tags: c#, websocket, buffer

Currently I am doing:

```
WebSocketReceiveResult result = await Conn.ReceiveAsync(readBuffer, token);
for (int i = 1; i <= result.Count; i++)
{
    if (CurrentPosition+i > ProcessedPosition)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
    }
    Console.Write(readBuffer.Array[CurrentPosition+i]);
    Console.ResetColor();
}
CurrentPosition += result.Count;
```

Am I even picking the proper positions in the buffer? How can I analyze it byte by byte?

Comment: Impossible to tell based on what you've posted.  What is `CurrentPosition`?  Why are you string your loop at 1 instead of 0?  You've asked it to fill in `readBuffer` why would you not simply read from the start of `readBuffer`?

Comment: CurrentPosition is the current position, starts with 0, since WebSocketReceiveResult count indicates the number of bytes received I figured I will have to set the for i to start with 1 and end with count. The whole thing is in a do while loop, ReceiveAsync contanstly receives live data so I need to process it realtime.

Comment: I don't see how you'd ever read the first byte (byte 0) by doing that.